# How to quickly prepare snails?

Tags: food-safety, outdoor-cooking, snail

How to quickly prepare fresh snails?

I've heard snails must be soaked in salted water for a few hours in order to remove the mucus but a friend of mine suggested that the ones in shells can be simply thrown into the hot ash and after a dozen of minutes they can be taken off the shell and eaten.

Was he right? What is the fastest way to prepare snail for eating? I mean, fastest way to prepare them so, that they would be safe food (killed parasites etc.)

Comment: Originally posted on outdoors.stackexchange.com  He may be looking for edible, not tasty.

Comment: Exactly, edible, not harmful, in extreme situations only. I have snails preparation in cookbok, but it requires time and access to kitchen ;)

Comment: Well first, I'd start hunting around for some wild garlic.

Comment: @Chris- Always my first priority in survival situations.

Comment: @Sobachatina - Well, if we can't survive like Ladies and Gentlemen, what's the point?

Comment: See also http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/14300/would-boiling-make-escargot-safe-if-they-were-carrying-parasites-or-bacteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way would be simply to boil them in salted water for a few minutes.

Throwing them on ashes (a barbecue?) would do the trick also, but I guess you might want to leave them there for more than a few minutes to ensure they were cooked throughout, and theres a bigger danger they'd overcook.

Comment: NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!!!!!!!! Save me!!!!!!!